# NextJS can't figure out why nothing renders from simple prop passing to display a p tag? (Data fetching and displau)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm doing some work in NextJS and I needed to render a card so I created the api endpoint setup the query debugged incorrect client state on the page and now it appears that my state variables are correct but I am still not rendering what I would expect.

I'm trying to render a JSON object that looks like this:

```
[{"id":"cla02oxnl0000txe0vzncxq7o","creator":"cl9x4lmhv00021snptuymv0vr","broken_item":"","issue_desc":"","loc":"","active":true,"prio":"Low"}]
```

And I can see a valid JSON object in the list of tickets I want to render:
Client side in the console by logging the tickets array.[image: Tickets array]

But I must have some syntax or misunderstanding of how I'm allowed to render here is my code for the page render:

```
if (!currentSession) {
    return (<div> No Session</div>)
}
return (
    <div>
        {console.log(tickets)}
        {tickets.map(({creator,broken_item, issue_desc, loc, prio,active}) => {
            <TicketGUI creator={creator} broken_item={broken_item} issue_desc={issue_desc} loc ={loc} prio={prio}/>
        })}
    </div>
)
```

And the component that is trying to render it's own props just looks like this:

```
export default function TicketGUI(props){

    return <p> {props} </p>
}
```

Comment: Maybe just `{JSON.stringify(props)}` if you're trying to see that the values are being passed down as expected.

Comment: Yup need to stringify but that was easy to debug my issue is that before it was throwing no errors but just no displaying anything and it's because map returned undefined as I forgot return the JSX Element.

Answer (score 0):

I had the syntax slightly off but my main issue is that I forgot to return something inside the anonymous function inside the map.  This will fix the issue and render:

```
return (
        <div>
            {}
            {tickets.map(
                ({creator,broken_item, issue_desc, loc, prio,active,creatorName}) => {
                    return(
                        <li key={listLength++}>
                            <TicketGUI creator={creator} broken_item={broken_item} issue_desc={issue_desc} loc ={loc} prio={prio} active={active} name={creatorName}/>
                        </li>
                    )
                }
            )}
        </div>
)
```